# The tensor product ti() in GAM package gives incorrect results

Tags: tensor, predict, gam

I am surprising to notice that it is somehow difficult to obtain a correct fit of interaction function from `gam()`.

To be more specific, I want to estimate an additive function:

`y=m_1(x)+m_2(z)+m_{12}(x,z)+u,`

where `m_1(x)=x^2`, `m_2(z)=z^2`,`m_{12}(x,z)=xz`. The following code generate this model:

```
test1 <- function(x,z,sx=1,sz=1) { 

  #--m1(x) function
  m.x<-x^2
  m.x<-m.x-mean(m.x)

  #--m2(z) function
  m.z<-z^2
  m.z<-m.z-mean(m.z)

  #--m12(x,z) function
  m.xz<-x*z
  m.xz<-m.xz-mean(m.xz)
  m<-m.x+m.z+m.xz

  return(list(m=m,m.x=m.x,m.z=m.z,m.xz=m.xz))
}

n <- 1000
a=0
b=2

x <- runif(n,a,b)/20
z <- runif(n,a,b)
u <- rnorm(n,0,0.5)
model<-test1(x,z)

y <- model$m + u
```

So I use `gam()` by fitting the model as

```
b3 <- gam(y~ ti(x) + ti(z) + ti(x,z))
vis.gam(b3);title("tensor anova")

#---extracting basis matrix
B.f3<-model.matrix.gam(b3)

#---extracting series estimator
b3.hat<-b3$coefficients
```

*Question:* when I plot the estimated function by `gam()`above against its true function, I end up with

```
par(mfrow=c(1,3))

#---m1(x)
B.x<-B.f3[,c(2:5)]
b.x.hat<-b3.hat[c(2:5)]
plot(x,B.x%*%b.x.hat)
points(x,model$m.x,col='red')
legend('topleft',c('Estimate','True'),lty=c(1,1),col=c('black','red'))

#---m2(z)
B.z<-B.f3[,c(6:9)]
b.z.hat<-b3.hat[c(6:9)]
plot(z,B.z%*%b.z.hat)
points(z,model$m.z,col='red')
legend('topleft',c('Estimate','True'),lty=c(1,1),col=c('black','red'))

#---m12(x,z)
B.xz<-B.f3[,-c(1:9)]
b.xz.hat<-b3.hat[-c(1:9)]
plot(x,B.xz%*%b.xz.hat)
points(x,model$m.xz,col='red')
legend('topleft',c('Estimate','True'),lty=c(1,1),col=c('black','red'))
```

However, the function estimate of `m_1(x)` is largely different from `x^2`, and the interaction function estimate `m_{12}(x,z)` is also largely different from `xz` defined in `test1` above. The results are the same if I use `predict(b3)`.

I really can't figure it out. Can anybody help me out by explaining why the results end up with this? Greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the problem of the above issue is not due to the package, of course. It is closely related to the identification conditions of the smooth functions. One common practice is to impose the assumptions that `E(mj(.))=0` for all individual function `j=1,...,d`, and `E(m_ij(x_i,x_j)|x_i)=E(m_ij(x_i,x_j)|x_j)=0` for i not equal to j. Those conditions require one to employ centered basis function in series estimator, which has been done already in GAM package. However, in my case above, function `m(x,z)=x*z` defined in `test1` does not satisfy the above identification assumptions, since the integral of `x*z` with respect to either `x` or `z` is not zero when x and z have range from zero to two.

Furthermore, series estimator allows the individual and interaction function to be identified if one impose `m(0)=0` or `m(0,x_j)=m(x_i,0)=0`. This can be readily achieved if we center the basis function around zero. I have tried both cases, and they work well whenever DGP satisfies the identification conditions.